# Pin vs Port terminology in SDC

Tags: vlsi, asic, timing-analysis, sdc

In SDC (Synopsys Design Constraints), `set_driving_cell` is said to be used to model the drive resistance of the cell driving the **input port**. I'm confused by the word input port, is this the input port of every cell in the netlist? Or just the top level input port of the whole design?

Below is the statement from the SDC documentation:
[image]

The same with `set_max_fanout` where it is said to be the max fanout for all **output pins** in the design. Is this the output pin of every cell in the netlist? Or just the top level output pins? Below is the statement from the SDC documentation:

[image]

I'm even more confused since the first one uses the word `port` while the second one uses the word `pin`.

Comment: Does the below answer answers your question..?

Answer (score 1):

A `port` is nothing but `pin` of the top-level design. The constraint `set_driving_cell` is used at the input ports of top-level design typically. It is not used with pins in internal modules, because their drivers and their driving strengths are deducible/already known to the STA tool. While `set_max_fanout` may be used with output ports and all internal pins which are drivers.

You can use either `pin` or `port` with `set_driving_cell`. Both have same intent in timing analysis. For e.g: `[get_pins idata_ff/D]`, where `idata_ff` is the flop in the synthesised logic netlist to which `idata` port is connected.

But  `port` gives you abstraction at HDL level and portability/flexibility, as you never have to worry about the pin of the gate/flop in the synthesised netlist to which the port is actually connected to. You can simply
constraint as `[get_ports idata]` as in the top-level HDL.